# Retrofit 2: JSON ответы переменной структуры

Tags: android, json, retrofit

Впервые пытаюсь работать со структурами ответов, которые могут меняться.

Есть response структура:

```
public class GetAuthResponse implements Serializable {
    @SerializedName("status")
    public int status;
    @SerializedName("request_hash")
    public String request_hash;
    @SerializedName("hash")
    public String hash;
    @SerializedName("data")
    @Nullable
    public Tokens data;
    @SerializedName("errors")
    @Nullable
    public Errors errors;

    public class Tokens {
        public String token;
        public String ptoken;
    }

    public class Errors {
        public int status;
        public String name;
        public String description;
    }
}
```

где есть 2 случая:

```
1. вернулось status+request_hash+hash+data
2. вернулось status+request_hash+hash+errors
```

то есть на запрос вернутся или данные или информация об ошибке
как видите первые 3 поля одинаковые, а вот data и errors могут приходить: или data или errors

я выделил аннотацией @Nullable - в надежде, что оно просто пропустит отсутствующую ветку и заполнит только то, что есть. Но увы меня постоянно выкидывает в **onFailure** обработчик

подскажите, как мне сделать так, чтобы тело ответа могло иметь вариативный формат, но не полностью абстрактный (не хочется парсить JSON ручками), а на с возможно отсутсвующими полями(нодами)

Comment: можно глянуть лог ошибку?

Comment: Какой статус код ответа в случае ошибки?

Comment: Задача решается, только лог нужен)

Comment: ошибка такая:
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 58 path $.errors

ну и ответ такой:

{
    "status": 37565820,
    "request_hash": "1",
    "hash": "",
    "errors": [
        {
            "status": 37565820,
            "name": "header",
            "description": ".... bla bla bla ...."
        }
    ]
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исправьте

```
public Errors errors;
```

на

```
public List<Errors> errors;
```

Comment: ааа. вижу вижу. Не обратил внимание на []. Сейчас программера, который формирует этот массив попрошу убрать []